# How to use date data type in either MS Access or SQL Server when using ODBC connection

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ms-access, odbc

I have a program in C# which connects to a database using a DSN (ODBC driver).

All queries I run in the program uses SQL. All works well but when using datetime data type in queries (in SELECT statement or in WHERE clause).

When DSN is a MS ACCESS database, I have to use something like this:

```
WHERE SomeDate = #1/1/2005#
```

But if the same database is in SQL Server, i should use something like this:

```
WHERE SomeDate = '1/1/2005'
```

Is there a way to manage this in the same program without doing a routine for SQL Server and another for MS ACCESS?

I tried by getting properties of OdbcConnection object, but I could not find a way to detect if driver is MS Access or SQL Server.

Comment: Use SQL parameters and pass an actual date and there is no problem

Comment: If you do use literals for sql server, you should always use `yyyy-mm-dd` rather than `1/1/2005`. The latter format could be m/d or d/m.

Comment: Have you considered parameterized queries? That way, dates et.al. don't need to be enclosed.

Comment: @DanGuzman Yes.. I have thought about it, but that is my last chance, since the query is already created and executed by mean of "cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() method. I don't want to make more changes to the source code.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have used data type *Datetime2* in SQL Server. That will be read as text if using the native *SQL Server* ODBC driver.

So either:

1. Use the Microsoft® ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server® - or newer, 17 is current:

[Microsoft® ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server®](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56567)

2. Change the data type of the field to *DateTime*

Answer (score 0):

You can set your Access database to be in ANSI-92 mode. This will allow you to query date fields with single quotes.

A word of warning though if this is an existing database or there are other applications using it. This may introduce a breaking change to any existing queries in your database that are not ANSI compliant. Likewise, if there are other applications using this database their queries may also break.

Also as an alternative, please note that `OdbcConnection` does have a `Driver` property that you can probe to determine the data source. On my machine, a DSN pointing to a SQL Server database returns `sqlncli11.dll`, because I am using the SQL Server Native Client 11.0. You can use this property to drive the syntax of your queries in your application. You could create a data access layer that abstracts some of this away from the rest of your code.

Comment: Can that mode be set per program? I am using a database that is used by other program as well.... so, if I change the mode to the database, possibly may affect the behaviour of the other program.

Comment: Which version of access?

Comment: You  absolutely NEVER EVER want to use this option on a existing database. Every single query with things like "**" use for wild card will now break because you have to use like "Smi%"  in place of Access "Smi*".  This option is ONLY a choice if from day one the WHOLE application was created this way - once you choose "one way" or the "the other way", then all your existing SQL has to be modified to conform with your given choice. Out of the blue flipping this option will make a HUGE massive mess of a existing application (since many sql statements will now be in wrong format).

Comment: @jstuardo p.s. I tried creating an OdbcConnection for both a SQL Server source and MS Access. While the driver property is empty for access, it is sqlncli11.dll for SQL Server, so that can also be used to differentiate across the data sources.

Comment: @MehdiIbrahim you mean something like "if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(conn.Driver)) dateLimiter = "'";"? So, when something is in Driver property, the limiter should be the single quote? I will test it. Thanks.

Comment: Yes. I obviously dont know what your code looks like, but try to avoid having that all over the place. If you can set a flag or enum once to indicate whether you're using access or SQL server, that will be better

Comment: To be fair, flipping Access into SQL ANSI mode is MOST certainly a way to solve the posters question. Once flipped, then the same sql in .net and Access can and will work. However I will state this is in general not a workable solution for Access developed from the start with ANSI sql not turned on. So while I gave a "harsh" warning - the ANSI option is in fact the ONLY way to solve this question. Flipping access into ANSI sql will result in both your .net SQL and the SQL you use in Access being the same.

Comment: I've updated my answer to caution future users to consider the implications of this flag.